# Is Pandas.tslib.normalize_date() timezone aware?

Tags: python, pandas, timezone

I found the following behaviour at normalizing Timestamps at daylight saving time change boundaries at pandas 0.16.2:

```
import pandas as pd
original_midnight = pd.Timestamp('20121104', tz='US/Eastern')
original_midday = pd.Timestamp('20121104T120000', tz='US/Eastern')

str(pd.tslib.normalize_date(original_midday))
`Out[10]:'2012-11-04 00:00:00-05:00'`

str(original_midnight)
`Out[12]:'2012-11-04 00:00:00-04:00'`
```

I believe the normalized Timestamp should have the same timezone than the original_midnight.

Is it a bug, or do I miss something?

Answer (score 1):

The [implementation](https://github.com/pydata/pandas/blob/6c48d12d090f0a3f4d9a5c2d891e56f4485476e2/pandas/tslib.pyx#L4303-L4317) simply truncates the time.  It does not appear to manipulate the offset at all, so I will say *no*, it is not timezone aware.

Also, consider that this type of operation (in many languages) tends to gloss over the fact that not every local day *has* a midnight.  For example, if the time zone is `'America/Sao_Paulo'` (Brazil), and the date is on the spring-forward transition (such as `2015-10-18`), the hour from 00:00 to 00:59 is skipped, meaning the start of the day is actually 01:00.  If the function were to be updated to be timezone aware, it would have to adjust the time as well as the offset.